# Making efficient use of \writes

Tags: tex-core, auxiliary-files, write

I'm currently trying to compile my thesis using LaTeX and have run up against the old `! No room for a new \write .` problem.  After some googling it seems the only way to actually resolve this problem is to restructure your document to minimise the number of writes being consumed.

To that end I've been looking through the `.log` to find where they are all being consumed. Here's the results grepped down to those lines containing `write`.

```
\write18 enabled.
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rvwrite/rvwrite.sty
Package: rvwrite 2010/08/25 1.2 enhanced write registers (CVR)
Package rvwrite Warning: ****************************************
(rvwrite)                Package rvwrite v,1.2 loaded
(rvwrite)                [enhanced write registers (CVR)]
(rvwrite)                ****************************************.
\rvtwrite=\write3
\openout3 = `thesis-write.tex'.
\@glossaryfile=\write4
\@outemp=\write5
\verbatim@out=\write6
runsystem(echo 'write18-test-20114121256'>"thesis.w18")...executed.
\w@pgf@writea=\write7
\tikzexternal@outfile=\write8
\glswrite=\write9
\glo@main@file=\write10
\FV@OutFile=\write11
\@outlinefile=\write12
\tikzexternal@dep@file=\write13
\tikzexternal@outmakefile=\write14
\tf@tdo=\write15
```

Where have `\write0`, `\write1` & `\write2` gone? Is the use of these somehow restricted?

I'm using standard packages: `algorithm2e`, `listings`, `glossaries`, `pgf`/`tikz`, `emp`. Some of these appear quite greedy with the resources. `glossaries` has claimed `\write4`, `\write9`, and `\write10`. `verbatim` and `fancyvrb` are loaded by other packages and they claim `\write6` and `\write11` respectively. The worst culprit seems to be PGF/TikZ taking four writes.

My compilation breaks when LaTeX is trying to construct the Table of Contents listings. I want to make a ToC, a list of Figures, Tables, Listings, and Algorithms. At present there are no where near enough writes to do this. Does anyone have any advice about how I can control the rampant `\write` consumption of these packages?

How do people actually make sizable documents using LaTeX with such restrictions? Am I being unreasonable assuming I'll be able to have a 7 chapter document with a ToC, 4 listofs, index, glossary, and bibliography? Or is that beyond the resource limits of LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Are you in fact using the package `rvwrite`? Its goal is to allow for more writing streams _if other packages use it_ Otherwise, it just uses some streams for no benefit.

Comment: @Bruno: I'm not using rvwrite. I added it in the hope it might help. If I remove it, then it frees up one more register and the compilation can get one listing further. The underlying problem still remains.

Comment: Somewhat related, [tex core - debug No room for a new \write problem - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154781/debug-no-room-for-a-new-write-problem?rq=1)

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately there are only 16 output register in TeX and eTeX didn't expanded that number. :-(

The output registers 0, 1 and 2 are already used by (La)TeX itself, e.g. for the `.log` file and always open, so you don't see them in the `.log` file.

It's a pity that `moreverb` and `fancyvrb` consume a write register each even when you might not use the verbatim write function. If you are sure that these registers are never used you could turn back the write register counter so that these register are reassigned the next time. This can be done with `\advance\count17 by -1` because the next to-be-assigned write register is stored in `\count17`.

Also PGF/TikZ itself only consumes one register. The other three are taken by the `external` library. I assume you are using it to speed up compilation, which should matter in the final compilation run. You could disable the List Of X'es during the writing process but then disable this library when you want to compile a "final" version. A good alternative to this library is the `standalone` class and package (written by me) where you put your TikZ pictures in external files which can be either included as source and compiled to PDF images which are then included. The upcoming version will allows to switch between both on-the-fly. It doesn't use any write register. (I really have to push the release ...)

Comment: At the moment my PGF/TikZ images are actually generated from embedded R code using Cameron Bracket's pgfSweave package. It would be nontrivial to switch to your standalone package. 
The information about (La)TeX's register allocation is invaluable (though it confirms my fears!).

Comment: The log file doesn't use up a write register. To quote the texbook: "if the number is negative or greater than 15 then the output goes to log" (and in the second case also to the terminal). I must say that I never quite understood why latex allocates \write0 (\@unused).

Comment: @Ulrike: Thanks, I just assumed that one was for the `.log`, didn't had time to study the TeXBook for it. I saw that `\write0` is used by `\typeout`.

Comment: Yes `\typeout` uses `write\@unused` = `\write0`. But this simply write to the log and the screen, so why not use e.g. `\write43`?

Comment: @Martin: I guess that many of the write streams are not active at the same time. Would it be possible to fool `\newwrite` into allocating the same streams to different packages?

Comment: @Bruno: Yes, you would have to read and set the `\count17` value appropriately.

Comment: These packages should have an option to enable the use of writes only on demand. For backwards compatibility they would need to have an option to switch it off instead.

Comment: `\let\oldnewwrite\newwrite`, `\let\newwrite\@gobble`, `\usepackage{...}`, `\let\newwrite\oldnewwrite`?

Comment: @Bruno: Yes, I had such an idea myself but went for the advance-by-minus-one method instead. It's shorter :-) Of course you need to know how many `\newwrite`s appear in the package, otherwise redefining `\newrite` like you did is the way to go.

Comment: @Bruno: Naturally packages can share a write stream - but not if both want to write continuarly during the compilation (e.g. at every shipout) to their file. I don't see how LaTeX/`\newwrite` should be able to decide if 2 `\newwrite` requests will interfer. I think LaTeX should offer an stream for "immediate" writing which all packages could use (I'm using \write0 for this but it can interfer with error messages so I'm not feeling that this is really satisfactory) and packages should make an effort to save write streams. That the pgf library uses up 3 streams is simply mad.

Comment: @Ulrike,Bruno: Yes, I strongly agree. There should be one write register for stuff which is written only locally while no code of another package is active. A good example would be the `filecontents` environment and other verbatim write operations. You could check if the `\write15` was not already allocated and use it, otherwise raise the usual warning.

Comment: @Martin: rather than checking that `\write15` is not allocated, I'd check that it is not opened (if possible?). I have some code to hack into `\write` to detect a use of `\immediate` before (similar to a recent question about detecting prefixes for `\def`). So I think that it is possible in principle in a LaTeX2e context to make an efficient use of writes.

Comment: @Bruno: I thought about checking if it is really open, which would further improve the situation. Unfortunately there seems to be no `\ifeof` or `\ifopen` for `\write` registers. Using some `\write` hackery didn't crossed my mind.

Comment: @Martin: In fact, the hackery would only be on `\immediate`, `\write`, `\openout`, and `\closeout`. These do not interact with any other primitive, not even `\afterassignment`.

Comment: why are both moreverb and fancyvrb used?-- surely fancyvrb  does everything moreverb can do?

Comment: Robin has updated `moreverb` to use a write stream only when needed: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/9a2d1272cedf940b

Answer (score 11):

> morewrites – Always room for a new write stream
>
> The pack­age aims to solve the er­ror “No room for a new \write”,
>   which oc­curs when the user or when the user’s pack­ages have
>   ’al­lo­cated too many streams us­ing \newwrite (TeX has a fixed
>   max­i­mum num­ber – 16 – [of] such streams built-in to its code). The
>   pack­age hooks into TeX prim­i­tive com­mands as­so­ci­ated with
>   writ­ing to files; it should be loaded near the be­gin­ning of the
>   se­quence of load­ing pack­ages for a doc­u­ment.

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/morewrites

Answer (score 6):

Note that the TikZ external library in 'mode=list and make' (which you appear to use) will dynamically (!) allocate more write registers than the default 'mode=convert with system call'.
Thus, eliminating the 'list and make' feature will automatically free at least one register.

In case you do not use \label or \ref in your tikz images, you can also use '\tikzexternalize[aux in dpth=false]' to de-activate support for \label and \ref. This will free a further write register (if I am not mistaken, pgf 2.10 also allocates it on-demand).

I have just committed a couple of changes to PGF CVS which allow more control over the used write registers of the externalization. Now, the registers used by the image externalization process are allocated on-demand if that is possible. Furthermore, the new version has a key '\tikzexternalize[disable dependency files]' which disables generation of .dep file dependencies -- freeing one more register at the cost of no longer being able to remake figures if data files changed.

I hope this helps - at least in the future.

Comment: This is awesome news Christian! However, Alastair is in the unfortunate position of needing exactly 4 more write streams in order to enable his `tableofcontents`, `listoffigures`, etc and keep figure externalization. So, TikZ needs to go all the way down to 0. Of course, this is an unreasonable demand for PdfTeX. But, do you think it would be possible to add logic that detects LuaTeX and automatically switches to the Luo IO Library?

Comment: @Sharpie: removing `rvwrite` which seems unused should solve the last of his prooblems, no?

Comment: Unfortunately, he still needed 4 with `rvwrite` disabled. Using fancy externalization + tables of contents/figures/algorithms/tables/etc allocates a full 8 registers. Add the 3 LaTeX allocates by default and you're up to 11 used out of 16 before really counting the piles of other packages that get loaded for a thesis. Not very nice :(. Which is why it would be awesome if we had a drop-in replacement for `newwrite` and friends that used the Lua IO libraries when available and deferred to standard TeX write registers otherwise.

Comment: @Sharpie I am interested in that LuaTeX mode ... but I do not have enough time to study your patch and/or the LuaTeX API in the moment. If you like, you can try to add the required switches. Perhaps PGF CVS already has a LuaTeX back-end driver or some switches to check for it. If you like, you can implement it, verify it exhaustively and let me know if you are ready. The requirement is that it remains backwards-compatible.

Comment: Sounds great! I was tinkering around last night with adding some code to `pgfutil-common.tex` that switched between output modes. Everything appears to work fine in `pdftex` mode, but something breaks in `pgfutil@IfFileExists` when it switches to `luatex` mode. So there is some more work to be done.

Answer (score 4):

I slapped together a quick patch to replace the `\newwrites` in TikZ with calls to Lua's IO library:

> https://gist.github.com/925047
>
> git://gist.github.com/925047.git

It's definitely amateur work---for example, I managed to break the makefile output as the commands required to build targets are missing. However, running a file with:

```
\tikzexternalize[mode=convert with system call]
```

Appears to be working fine and all of the images generated look ok. The patch was made against PGF 2.10 and will require that `lualatex -shell-escape` be used to compile the file. Hopefully this will free up 4 write streams for other purposes.

If someone who actually knows what they are doing when it comes to TeX programming has improvements to contribute, fork or comment away!

#### Update

---

I updated the patch and fixed a few dumb mistakes -- one of which was breaking the Makefile output.  So, the following should work now:

```
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]
```

Answer (score 1):

`morewrites` works indeed to remove the error `! No room for a new \write` but it broke the TOC and all "List of *" for me. I ended up using `scrwfile` instead (with `\usepackage{scrwfile}`).

Comment: It works perfectly !