# How to automatically increase the number of \write registers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, e-tex, write-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making efficient use of \writes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15665/making-efficient-use-of-writes)

I am trying to compile a document that heavily uses PGF/TikZ externalization as well as a table of contents, list of figures, etc.   I am running into error about

> `No room for 
>   a new \write.`

I have investigated the problem and the only suggestion I found is basically “re-structure your document,” which I don't want to do.  I found [a discussion on the tex-live list](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2007-March/thread.html#13302).

Does anyone know if anything came of this? Can I use it? I am hoping someone has an easy way to fix this problem, possibly a package I can load or some code I can add.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15665/making-efficient-use-of-writes.

Comment: Sorry, you can't increase the number of write registers. The number is fixed to 16 where the first three 0-2 are already used by LaTeX. See the recent question [Making efficient use of \writes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15665/making-efficient-use-of-writes) for an discussion. I tend to close this question as a duplicate of it.