# debug No room for a new \write problem

Tags: tex-core, glossaries, auxiliary-files, write

I have a template with an extensive documentation. (See [TemplateDocumentation.pdf](http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/download/latex/vorlagen/thesis/TemplateDocumentation.pdf)). It compiled several month ago. Now with updated packages it does not compile anymore because of the famous *No room for a new \write problem*.

Before everything was already tuned such that all writes are used. I had to disable packages to make it compile (and thus give up functionality). Now I can test that disabling for example pgf/tikz solves the original problem. But I would rather not give up pgf/tikz in my template... Note that I do not use the external package of tikz.

So the basic question is how to find out which packages are actually using \write. Some must have introduced an file output or consume more than before.

The code fails at that first time the `filecontents` package is used.

A minimal example for this problem is currently not available and would be really hard to create, Basically because the code basis is so huge.

I use this code to make writes less a problem, but it solves nothing really

```
\usepackage{morewrites}
% see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noroom
\usepackage{etex} 
\reserveinserts{28}
```

The packages I know of which use a \write and which I load are

- tikz/pgf
- imakeidx
- glossaries
- listings
- titletoc

The complete list of packages can be found in my documentation (see link) on page 240.

Comment: `etex` can't help, the maximum number of output streams is still 16.

Comment: As from v4.0 `glossaries` uses one extra write if you define entries in the document instead of the preamble. See the section [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs) in the glossaries user guide for further details.

Comment: As a fan of »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« you  might be interested in its »scrwfile« package. It is described in the user guide.

Comment: @egreg: Do I understand correct that loading the etec package has no effect? I added these lines because they are recommended by the FAQ.

Comment: Loading `etex` has no effect for the number of input and output streams that can be allocated and simultaneously open. This number is still 16 in all TeX engines (but, of course, LuaTeX can use different ways for writing to files). With `etex` you can access 32768 registers of the various types (counters, dimensions, boxex and so on) instead of the traditional 256.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech _what_ faq?  i’ve been working on mine today, and i don’t think it says anything about `\write` streams available with `etex` -- can you give me chapter and verse? (all my faq's pages have a link at the bottom of every page that eventually leads to the email address for reporting problems.)

Comment: Thank you, using the package "morewrites" already solved the problem for me.

Comment: Side note, LaTeX3 implements "garbage collection" mechanism for streams, so as a package author you should use \ior_new:N/\iow_new:N etc. instead of \newread/\newwrite which should solve most problems. Remember to not mix \ior_open with \openout however.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) this is just guessing, but if your document has defined acronyms or glossary entries within the `document` environment and you upgraded to version 4.0, an extra write is required. The reason for this is as follows:

Version 3.07¹ and below wrote the `name`, `description` and `symbol` fields to the external glossary files (in addition to the `sort` field). There are multiple issues with this:

1. Fragile commands within those fields need protecting otherwise an error occurs when the command is written to the file. To overcome this, `glossaries` had the `sanitize` package option which basically converted the contents of those fields to a list of letters, so for example, if you had `\cite` in the `description` field this would be converted from a macro into the five characters `\` `c` `i` `t` and `e`. This can now be safely written to the glossary file but if you attempted to display the `description` elsewhere in the document you'd actually get "\cite" in your PDF (or, more usually, "—cite" since the default serif font displays the character `\` as an em-dash).
2. Any occurrences of `makeindex` or `xindy` special characters need to be escaped. This is done by `glossaries` but the longer the `name`, `description`, and `symbol` fields, the longer this takes to do, so it slows the document build.
3. `makeindex` has a limited buffer and a long description can exceed this.
4. A custom glossary style may be required that should display other fields, but these can't be accessed if the entry hasn't been defined.

To overcome these issues version 4.0 changed the way entry information was written to the glossary file. Now only the `sort` field and `\glossentry{`*label*`}` are written to the file. It's then up to the glossary style to define `\glossentry` so that it accesses the relevant information using commands like `\glsentrydesc`. This means there are no longer any worries about using fragile commands, since they don't get written to the file. (The `sort` value is automatically sanitized by default and the label can't contain fragile commands anyway.) Since indexing information is now in a shorter string it's a lot quicker to do any escaping of `xindy`/`makeindex` characters (in case they appear in, say, the `sort` field or entry label). And there's no need to worry about exceeding `makeindex`'s buffer (unless you have an excessively long sort value or label).

There is, however, a drawback with this approach: all entries must be defined when the glossary is displayed in order for `\glossentry` to access the relevant fields. If the glossary is displayed at the end of the document, this isn't a problem, but quite often users like to have a list of acronyms or notation in the front matter. To get around this, and to ensure backward compatibility, `glossaries` modifies the definition of `\newglossaryentry` at the start of the `document` environment so the glossary information is written to a temporary file `\jobname.glsdefs`, which is then input at the start of the document on the next LaTeX run.

This ensures that the entry information is available when displaying the glossary, but there is the drawback of an extra write, expansion issues can occur and any changes to the definitions don't get picked up until the next run. The `see` key also doesn't work as it's not saved in a field (it simply triggers the cross-referencing when the entry is defined) and so doesn't get written to the `.glsdefs` file. It also means that terms defined using `\newacronym` are converted to a regular entry definition, which can cause a problem for the abbreviation mechanism.

See also [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs) in the `glossaries` user manual.

**MWE1:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\begin{document}

\gls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Here `glossaries` defines two writes: one for the `.ist` file and one for the `.glo` file.

**MWE2:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{long form}

\begin{document}

\gls{sample}. \gls{xyz}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Here `glossaries` defines three writes: one for the `.ist` file, one for the `glo` file and one for the `.acn` file.

**MWE3:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{long form}

\gls{sample}. \gls{xyz}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Here `glossaries` defines four writes: one for the `.ist` file, one for the `.glo` file, one for the `.acn` file and one for the `.glsdefs` file.

**MWE4:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,index,symbols,numbers]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{long form}

\gls{xyz}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Here `glossaries` defines seven writes: `.ist`, `.glo`, `.acn`, `.idx` (from the `index` option), `.nlo` (from the `numbers` option), `.slo` (from the `symbols` option) and `.glsdefs` (because `\newacronym` is in the `document` environment).

The [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) package provides the option `docdef=restricted` which allows document definitions but doesn't create the `.glsdefs` file. This means that the terms must be defined before the glossaries are displayed, but it means that an extra `\write` isn't required.

**MWE5:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,docdef=restricted]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{long form}

\gls{sample}. \gls{xyz}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Now there are three writes: one for the `.ist` file, one for the `.glo` file and one for the `.acn` file.

**How to Minimise the Number of new `\write`s**

1. Move all instances of `\newglossaryentry` (and `\newacronym` which uses `\newglossaryentry`) to the preamble or to a file that's loaded in the preamble either via `\input` or `\loadglsentries` ([don't use `\include`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#include)).
2. Make sure you haven't defined a glossary that you don't intend to use. For example:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

   \makeglossaries

   \newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{long form}

   \begin{document}

   \gls{xyz}.

   \printglossaries

   \end{document}
   ```

   Here `glossaries` defines three new writes: one for the `.ist` file, one for the `.glo` file and one for the `.acn` file, but one of these (`.glo`) isn't being used. This is a waste of a `\write` so suppress the `main` glossary using the `nomain` package option:

   ```
   \usepackage[nomain,acronym]{glossaries}
   ```
3. If you don't need to make any further modifications to the `.ist` file, allow `glossaries` to generate it on the first build:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[nomain,acronym]{glossaries}

   \makeglossaries

   \newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{long form}

   \begin{document}

   \gls{xyz}.

   \printglossaries

   \end{document}
   ```

   Then suppress it's creation by adding `\noist` to your document:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[nomain,acronym]{glossaries}

   \noist
   \makeglossaries

   \newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{long form}

   \begin{document}

   \gls{xyz}.

   \printglossaries

   \end{document}
   ```

   Now `glossaries` only defines one new write for the `.acn` file.
4. Use the `savewrites` package option. This uses just one write for the `.ist` and all the `.glo`, `.acn` etc files (but not for the `.glsdefs` file). With this option `glossaries` stores all the glossary information in tokens until the end of the document and then iterates through each glossary and writes to each of the glossary files reusing the same write register. This slows the document build, but provided you define all your entries in the preamble `glossaries` only defines the one write register.

   **This method is susceptible to TeX's asynchronous output routine and can cause the locations to be incorrect.**

   This option slows the build because whenever you reference an entry (using commands like `\gls` or `\glsadd`) information is appended to a token register. At the end of the document, `glossaries` then iterates through each defined glossary and writes the contents of the associated token register to the external glossary file. This takes longer than simply writing a line every time you use a command like `\gls` or `\glsadd`. How much longer it takes depends on the number of times you reference each entry.

As from `glossaries` version 4.04, there's another option that doesn't create any new files, as the sorting and indexing is done by TeX rather than using an external indexing application:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newacronym{xyz}{XYZ}{long form}

\begin{document}

\gls{xyz}. \gls{sample}.

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

This just creates the standard `.log` and `.aux` files (as well as the `.pdf`/`.dvi` file). In this case, `\newglossaryentry` and `\newacronym` are made preamble-only commands so there's no `.glsdefs` file. However, this method is very inefficient, has difficulties with hierarchical entries and can only sort according to the basic Latin set. It's therefore not recommended except as a last resort.

The `glossaries-extra` package provides two other methods that don't use any `\write` registers:

Just use `\printunsrtglossary` (or `\printunsrtglossaries`) to display the glossaries. This simply iterates over all defined entries (so they need to be defined first). There's no sorting and no location lists.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{zoo}{name={zoo},description={sample description}}
\newglossaryentry{aardvark}{name={aardvark},description={sample description}}

\begin{document}

\gls{aardvark}.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

There are no `\write` registers created here, but the glossary is in order of definition and includes both entries even though only one has been used in the document.

The other option is to use `glossaries-extra` with [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls). This involves a slight modification to the above. The entries are now defined in a `.bib` file. For example, `entries.bib`:

```
@entry{zoo,name={zoo},description={sample description}}
@entry{aardvark,name={aardvark},description={sample description}}
```

The document file now needs the `record` option and `\GlsXtrLoadResources` to specify the `.bib` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src=entries]% terms defined in entries.bib

\begin{document}

\gls{aardvark}.

\printunsrtglossaries

\end{document}
```

This doesn't define any `\write` registers (all the information is written to the `.aux` file) but now only the indexed entry (aardvark) appears in the glossary, the glossary is sorted and the entries have location lists. (Although in this case there's only one entry.)

The document build process (assuming the document file is called `myDoc.tex`) is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

(Replace `pdflatex` with `xelatex` etc, as appropriate.) If you want letter groups, you'll need the `--group` (or `-g`) switch:

```
bib2gls --group myDoc
```

This works in a different manner to the `makeindex`/`xindy` approach. `bib2gls` reads the required information from the `.aux` file and creates a file with the entry definitions that's input by `\GlsXtrLoadResources`. The entry's are first sorted before writing their definitions and only those indexed in the document are included. This means that the glossary can simply be displayed using `\printunsrtglossaries`, as in the previous example. `bib2gls` creates a transcript file (`.glg`) and one `.glstex` file per resource command (`\GlsXtrLoadResources`) but no `\write` register needs allocating for any glossary files.

There's [a table comparing the various methods](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#tab:options) in the `glossaries` user manual.

By way of comparison, `bib2gls` comes with [some example documents](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls/examples), including [`sample-multi2.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/sample-multi2.tex) which has 14 glossaries and 1 index. The `main` glossary is suppressed with `nomain`, the index glossary is created with the `index` package option and the remaining glossaries are created with `\newglossary*`:

```
\usepackage[record,% use bib2gls
 section,% use \section* for glossary headings
 postdot,% insert dot after descriptions in glossaries
 nomain,% don't create 'main' glossary
 index,% create 'index' glossary
 nostyles,% don't load default styles
% load and patch required style packages:
 stylemods={list,mcols,tree,bookindex}
]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary*{bacteria}{Bacteria}
\newglossary*{markuplanguage}{Markup Languages}
\newglossary*{vegetable}{Vegetables}
\newglossary*{mineral}{Minerals}
\newglossary*{animal}{Animals}
\newglossary*{chemical}{Chemical Formula}
\newglossary*{baseunit}{SI Units}
\newglossary*{measurement}{Measurements}
\newglossary*{film}{Films}
\newglossary*{book}{Books}
\newglossary*{person}{People}
\newglossary*{mediacontrol}{Media Control Symbols}
\newglossary*{information}{Information Symbols}
\newglossary*{weather}{Weather Symbols}
```

The document loads `hyperref`, so this means that a write register (`\@outlinefile`) is created for `hyperref`'s `.out` file in addition to the standard write registers `\@mainaux` and `\@partaux` defined by the LaTeX kernel. (If a table of contents is added, this would create a additional write register for the `.toc` file.)

If the document were changed to use `makeindex`/`xindy`, then it would require 1 write register for the style file and one per glossary (including the index) = 1 + 15 = 16. With the 2 registers defined by the kernel and `hyperref`'s register for the PDF bookmarks, this means that the document would require **19** write registers (or 20 if the `.glsdefs` file is created if any glossary definitions are moved to the `document` environment).

With `bib2gls` only the 2 registers defined by the kernel and `hyperref`'s `.out` register are created giving a total of **3** write registers, which is a significant saving.

In terms of associated temporary files, there are the standard `.aux` and `.log` files and `hyperref`'s `.out` file. With `makeindex`/`xindy` there's also the style file and three files per glossary (input, output and transcript), which gives a total of 2 (`.aux` and `.log`) + 1 (`.out`) + 1 (`.ist`/`.xdy`) + 3 × 15 = 49.

With `bib2gls`, there's the transcript `.glg` file and 1 `.glstex` file per `\GlsXtrLoadResources`. The number of resource commands isn't related to the number of glossaries. One resource command may process multiple glossaries (if they have the same settings) or one glossary may require multiple resource commands (if it's divided into independently sorted blocks). In the case of [`sample-multi2.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/sample-multi2.tex) there are 9 resource commands, so the total number of associated temporary files = 2 (`.aux` and `.log`) + 1 (`.out`) + 1 (`.glg`) + 9 (`.glstex`) = 13. (The result [`sample-multi2.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/sample-multi2.pdf) is also available on CTAN.)

So using `bib2gls` not only removes the need for write registers associated with the glossaries but can also reduce the total number of temporary files.

---

¹ Versions between 3.07 and 4.0 were experimental and weren't uploaded to CTAN.

Comment: What is the slow down by using `savewrites`? The problem was now solved by moving all definitions in the examples before `\begin{document}`. This however required some more work on my latex examples package... Using `nomain` was no option since I create all possible lists in my documentation.

Comment: Just tested `savewrites` it fails compilation in your code at `\RequirePackage{glossaries-compatible-307}` with the error `\glswritefiles undefined.`

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech what version of `glossaries` are you using?

Comment: @NicolaTalob Version 4.02 shipped by Miktex.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Should be fixed in 4.03. Allow a few days for the new version to propagate through the mirrors and get into the TeX distributions.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Please see my note.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you so much for your wonderfully clear and detailed explanation with multiple MWEs. I'm now inspired to use the glossaries package in my thesis (I wasn't aware it existed). BTW I arrived here because I wanted to understand more about the morewrites package which enabled me to finally add a custom list type in my thesis. Thank you again.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with `morewrites` and the `filecontents` package, is the way `filecontents` defines a  `\newwrite` using `\ch@ck7\reserved@c\write` and by-passing the `morewrites` mechanism.

[Here](https://github.com/yannisl/phdfilecontents/blob/master/phdfilecontents.sty), is a hacked version which I use and by-passes the problem. Either Bruno or Scott Pakin need to fix it at the package level.

Comment: this is a lifesaver -- but why does your hacked package comment out the lines at the end that expose the change (without those lines it uses the default no-package filecontents)

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I was testing it with something else and commented the lines. Will fix, in case someone else finds this thread.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides This was very helpful. I was just about to open another question "Is the morewrites package compatible with the filecontents package?" Now I know.