# Difference between morewrites and scrwfile

Tags: packages, write

I have tested `morewrites` and `scrwfile` in my template which uses so many writes that without loading any of those packages I would run into the `no room for new \write` problem.

I find that with `scrwfile` I can use more packages that use an output. In my case these are

- TikZ and pgf (without external)
- `imakeidx`
- `glossaries`
- `fancyvrb`
- `listings`
- `titletoc`
- `todonotes` (?)

There may be more, but these are the ones that I know of which use `\write`

Technically I wonder If anyone can describe what are the differences between these packages and if there is a way to count the free `\write` outputs.

Comment: You can grep the log file to get an idea of the used (and thus free) write registers. It does not answer your question, but if you follow [these instructions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154857/7323) and use the noidx glossaries, you should gain more write registers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Difference between morewrites and scrwfile

morewrites aims at patching

- the TeX-primitives that are used for creating and writing to text 
  files, that is `\write`, `\openout` and `\closeout`.
- the `\newwrite`-macro that is used for allocating `\write`-registers
  and that in turn uses the `\openout`-primitive.

scrwfile aims at patching the `\@starttoc`-`\addtocontents`-`\@writefile`-mechanism provided by the LaTeX kernel for creating things like table of contents, list of figures, list of tables, etc.

> ...if there is a way to count the free `\write` outputs

The number of the last `\write`-register that was allocated in terms of `\newwrite` (the LaTeX-`\@starttoc`-`\addtocontents`-`\@writefile`-kernel-mechanism internally also uses `\newwrite`) is held in count-register 17
whereby count-register 17 is initialized to -1 before allocating any `\write`-register.
As `\write`-registers are numbered from 0 to 15, you can, e.g., have eTeX calculate the amount of such `\write`-registers that were allocated in terms of `\newwrite` via `\number\numexpr15-\number\count17\relax`.

Ulrich

Comment: Ok, Is it recommandable to use both packages?

Comment: I downvoted by accident and can't revert till the anwer is edited. I guess you will extend the answer to include Matthias' quetion. Can you ping me when done so i can upvote?