# Special package combination gives "No room for new \write."

Tags: table-of-contents, packages

In my special package combination I get the error `No room for new \write. \tablecontents` and `Bad number (16). \tablecontents`.
The following MWE throws this error in `pdflatex` and `lualatex` with TeX Live 2015.
As you can see, I add the own content register `loi`.
I can delete nearly every package separately and the error directly vanishes.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with this package combination?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% load packages
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\usepackage{adjustbox, amsmath, blindtext, datatool, fancybox, fixme, graphicx, marginnote, pgfplots}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% load package for code code highlighting
\usepackage{minted}

% define Open Issue and corresponding List of Open Issues
\newcommand{\openissue}[2][Unlabeled]{%
    \par%
    {\refstepcounter{loicounter}%
    \phantomsection% comment out if hyperref is noy used
    \addcontentsline{loi}{figure}{%
        \protect\numberline{%
            \ifcsname c@chapter\endcsname%
                \thechapter.%
            \fi%
            \theloicounter%
        }{#1: #2}%
    }%
    \textbf{Open Issue -- #1:} #2}%
    \par%
}
% define counter
\makeatletter
\ifcsname c@chapter\endcsname%
    \newcounter{loicounter}[chapter]%
\else
    \newcounter{loicounter}%
\fi%
\newcommand*{\listopenissuesname}{List of Open Issues}
\newcommand{\listofopenissues}{%
    \ifcsname chapter\endcsname%
        \chapter*{\listopenissuesname}%
    \else%
        \section*{\listopenissuesname}%
    \fi%
    \@starttoc{loi}%
}
\makeatother

\fxsetup{status = draft}
\makeglossaries
\makeindex

\begin{document}

% include open issues
\listofopenissues
% include list of corrections
\listoffixmes
% include indicies
\tableofcontents                            % Inhaltsverzeichnis einbinden

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you had a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154857/34551)?

Comment: According to Knuth, there are only 16 IO channels, which are normally allocated using \newread and \newwrite.  I don't believe they reuse closed channels automatically.

Comment: You may try adding `\usepackage{morewrites}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution is to use `\usepackage{morewrites}` since basically any of the packages already loaded there grabs at least one (write) file handle, but the number of file handles is restricted to 16 registers only, unless `morewrites` is loaded, which extends the number of registers.

The question is: Are some of the packages really needed?

Here is a short excerpt of the `\jobname.log` file

```
\@dtl@write=\write3   % package datatool
\Verbatim@Outfile=\write4  % fancyvrb
\w@pgf@writea=\write5  % pgf
\blx@bcfout=\write6   % biblatex
\FV@OutFile=\write7   % fancyvrb again
\@xs@message=\write8  % xstring
\minted@code=\write9  % minted
\glswrite=\write10    % glossaries
\glo@main@file=\write11  % glossaries again
\noroom@idxfile=\write12  % imakeidx
\@outlinefile=\write13    % hyperref?
\tf@loi=\write14          % code itself with \addcontentsline{loi}
\tf@lox=\write15          % fixme package
! No room for a new \write.
\tf@toc=\write16  % Failure here
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! You are right, I do not need all packages every time and will reduce them. However, I wanted to understand the problem. How do you get the file `jobname.log`?

Comment: @Dirk: Any TeX compilation run produces a `.log` file. If your file is called `foo.tex`, the jobname is `foo` and the log file is `foo.log` then. The information I presented in this answer is of course condensed, i.e. I took only the relevant lines with `\write...`

Comment: I did not realise that you condensed the information manually. Thanks!

Comment: @Dirk: Not manually. I used `grep` ;-)

Comment: I just realised, that you marked `lox` with my code. Where do I have the line `\addcontentsline{lox}` in my code?

Comment: @Dirk: Sorry, that's wrong of course. `lox` comes from `fixme`

Comment: Where do you find which package generated which line? I am trying to understand the `\write` in my log file based on your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why is it not enabled by default? You save my day.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX has a limit of 16 open files, and many packages open them.

There are 3 proposed solutions for this error that I could find:

- Use LuaLaTeX, and the limit will be the limit in the operating systems (never tried)
- Use the packages morewrites (used it for a while but later hit in a bug)
- Use the package scrwfile from KOMA-Script (My current choice)

morewrites and scrwfile have different approaches to solve this problem, but both change the LaTeX kernel somehow. Deep Magic.

See [debug No room for a new \write problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154781/debug-no-room-for-a-new-write-problem/154857#154857)

Comment: Some packages are not compatible with LuaLaTeX, but it looks to be the better solution overall.