# glossaries-extra: How to apply custom abbreviation styles while using bib2gls

Tags: xetex, glossaries, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I'm using `glossaries-extra` with the `bib2gls` option on a big document (I tried to use the standard method, with `\makeglossaries`, but I got the insufficient write buffers error).

My problem is this: when using `makeglossaries`, the abbreviation styles `withdesc` and `withoutdesc` are correctly applied, thus on first use, the short and long forms are printed. But that's not the case when using `bib2gls`: only the short form is printed.

MWE (I took this one since the document I'm creating is for real big):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[spanish]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=Crimson,
  linkcolor=Crimson,
  urlcolor=Crimson
}

\usepackage[record,acronym,postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\begin{filecontents}{terms.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8
@entry{duck,
    name = {duck},
    category = {withdesc},
    description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}
}

@entry{parrot,
    name = {parrot},
    category = {withdesc},
    description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}
}
\end{filecontents}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={terms}]

\begin{filecontents}{acros.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8
@acronym{GNU,
    user1 = {{\textit{GNU No es Unix}\, en español}},
    plural = {{GNUs}},
    short = {{GNU}},
    category = {{withoutdesc}},
    long = {{GNU is Not Unix}}
}

@acronym{TTL,
    plural = {TTLs},
    short = {TTL},
    category = {withdesc},
    long = {{Time To Live}},
    description = {{Some value}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={acros}]

\setabbreviationstyle[withdesc]{long-short-user-desc}
\setabbreviationstyle[withoutdesc]{long-short-user}

\newglossarystyle{customAbbrevList}{%
    \setglossarystyle{listhypergroup}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
            \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]%
        \glsifcategory{##1}{withoutdesc}{%
             --- \glsentrylong{##1}\ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}{ (\!\glscurrentfieldvalue)}{}%
        }{%
            \mbox{}\par\nobreak\csuse{@afterheading}%
            \glossentrydesc{##1}%
        }%
        \glspostdescription\space ##2%
    }%
}

\newglossarystyle{customGloList}{%
    \setglossarystyle{listhypergroup}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
            \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]%
        \glsifcategory{##1}{withoutdesc}%
        { ---}%
        {%
            {\mbox{}\par\nobreak\csuse{@afterheading}%
            \glossentrydesc{##1}}\glspostdescription%
        }%
        \space ##2%
    }%
}

\addto\captionsspanish{%
    \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abreviaturas}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Glosario}
}

\begin{document}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}. Also, this is \gls{GNU}.

Again: a \gls{duck}, and a \gls{parrot} are part of \gls{GNU}.

We have some \gls{TTL}; again, \gls{TTL}.

\printunsrtglossary[type=main,style=customGloList]
\printunsrtglossary[type=acronym,style=customAbbrevList]

\end{document}
```

The output of compiling the above document with:

```
xelatex doc.tex
bib2gls doc
xelatex doc.tex
```

is this:

[image: Output of compiling the document]

What should I do to get the long and short form of the terms printed correctly on first use [example: Time To Live (TTL)]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abbreviation styles must be set before the abbreviations are defined. Since they are defined in the `.glstex` file input by `\GlsXtrLoadResources` they need to be set before that command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[spanish]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=Crimson,
  linkcolor=Crimson,
  urlcolor=Crimson
}

\usepackage[record,acronym,postdot]{glossaries-extra}

\begin{filecontents}{terms.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8
@entry{duck,
    name = {duck},
    category = {withdesc},
    description = {a waterbird with webbed feet}
}

@entry{parrot,
    name = {parrot},
    category = {withdesc},
    description = {mainly tropical bird with bright plumage}
}
\end{filecontents}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={terms}]

\begin{filecontents}{acros.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8
@acronym{GNU,
    user1 = {{\textit{GNU No es Unix}\, en español}},
    plural = {{GNUs}},
    short = {{GNU}},
    category = {{withoutdesc}},
    long = {{GNU is Not Unix}}
}

@acronym{TTL,
    plural = {TTLs},
    short = {TTL},
    category = {withdesc},
    long = {{Time To Live}},
    description = {{Some value}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\setabbreviationstyle[withdesc]{long-short-user-desc}
\setabbreviationstyle[withoutdesc]{long-short-user}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={acros}]

\newglossarystyle{customAbbrevList}{%
    \setglossarystyle{listhypergroup}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
            \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]%
        \glsifcategory{##1}{withoutdesc}{%
             --- \glsentrylong{##1}\ifglshasfield{\glsxtruserfield}{\glscurrententrylabel}{ (\!\glscurrentfieldvalue)}{}%
        }{%
            \mbox{}\par\nobreak\csuse{@afterheading}%
            \glossentrydesc{##1}%
        }%
        \glspostdescription\space ##2%
    }%
}

\newglossarystyle{customGloList}{%
    \setglossarystyle{listhypergroup}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
            \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]%
        \glsifcategory{##1}{withoutdesc}%
        { ---}%
        {%
            {\mbox{}\par\nobreak\csuse{@afterheading}%
            \glossentrydesc{##1}}\glspostdescription%
        }%
        \space ##2%
    }%
}

\addto\captionsspanish{%
    \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Abreviaturas}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Glosario}
}

\begin{document}

A \gls{duck} and a \gls{parrot}. Lots of \glspl{duck}. Also, this is \gls{GNU}.

Again: a \gls{duck}, and a \gls{parrot} are part of \gls{GNU}.

We have some \gls{TTL}; again, \gls{TTL}.

\printunsrtglossary[type=main,style=customGloList]
\printunsrtglossary[type=acronym,style=customAbbrevList]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Comment: Thank you! `=)` It works in the example. Unfortunately, I made the change in my big document, and in fact it worked to an extent: the first use is set correctly, but the glossaries won't show the long name version of the entries. Could the cause of this be the glossary styles `customAbbrevList` and `customGloList`? (The `makeindex` approach worked just fine before the change).

Comment: I also think the issue could be the `.latexmkrc` file. Is running `bib2gls` necessary each time after running `xelatex`, or just one time? Thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: @JBFWP286 It's difficult to say without seeing the code. One thing I've just noticed is that you have `plural` instead of `shortplural`, which may confuse the style. Regarding your second comment, `bib2gls` needs to be run after `xelatex` whenever the definitions change (for example, if you modify the `.bib` file, add new instances of `\gls` etc, or if the page numbers change).

Comment: Ok. I tried changing the tag `plural` for `shortplural`, to no avail. I'll send you a link via chat with the important files (the preamble); of course it won't compile, but I tought the same about seeing the code `=(` Thank you so much!

Comment: @JBFWP286 I'm sorry, I can't work it out from that code. Here are some things to check: have a look at the `.glstex` file to make sure all the fields are present in the `\bibglsnewacronym` commands; try adding some of the debugging commands to the glossary to check the fields are assigned correctly. These are commands like `\showglodesc` described in the documented code (`texdoc glossaries-code`). For example `\showglodesc{##1}` inside `\glossentry` will interrupt the build and show the description field in the transcript. You can show the category with `\showglofield{##1}{category}`.

Comment: I made a quick debug, but finally gave up. I reverted back to using `makeglossaries`, with the `morewrites` package to allow more `\write` slots, as stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289734/special-package-combination-gives-no-room-for-new-write). Thank you so much for your patience and time @nicola-talbot! `=)`

Comment: @JBFWP286 That's okay. It's probably best to start using `bib2gls` on a new document rather than modifying a big existing one.