# \tableofcontent bug using biblatex, reledpar and arabtex

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, reledpar, arabtex

There is a weird bug where the `\tableofcontents` (toc) won't show up, when I use the packages `reledpar`, `biblatex` and `arabtex` simultaneously. Instead I get these two error messages:

"No room for a new \write. \tableofcontents"

and

"Bad number (16). \tableofcontents"

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibtotocnumbered]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=authoryear-ibid,pagetracker=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
    \section{Hello there}
    Hello and \textit{\RL{'hlAn}} to you!
\end{document}
```

When deactivating one of those packages the toc shows up fine.
Any ideas why these errors occur and how to solve them?

Comment: With `\usepackage{morewrites}` you can get around the limited number of `\write`s. Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289734/35864

Comment: `reledmac` and `reledpar` request quite a number or `\write`s. `arabtex` also requires two. `biblatex` needs one and loads `xstring` which uses another one. If you load all of these packages and request a toc you cross the magic number of 16 writes and get an error. `morewrites` allows you to ignore the limit of 16 `\write`s.

Comment: It is true, but there is reledmac options which are better than `morewrites`  package. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the answer! I'm not really deep into LaTeX and didn't know of those "16 writes". I will definitely try your different options. If I don't write anymore on this topic, consider it solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by moewe, your combination of all these packages make you need to many `\write` room.

You could use `morewrites` package, but you will get a very slow run. It is better to optimize your reledmac setting to avoid not need rule.

Reading § 4.2 of reledmac handbook, (that you would have find if you have looked for "room" in the reledmac handbook), you should use these options when loading :

- `noend` if you don't use endnotes
- `noeledsec` if you don't use `eledsection` tools
- `series={A}` if you use only A series of notes, `series={A,B}` if you use only A and B series of notes, etc.

There are other optimization options, that you should look on, but only these three ones have impact in `no room for a new \write` problem.