# Loading tcolorbox with the minted option breaks tikzexternalize and results in compilation error with makeglossaries

Tags: luatex, glossaries, tcolorbox, minted, tikz-external

I have a weird problem that has now been localised to either of the lines:

```
\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox} 
\makeglossaries{}
```

in my preamble. I am using `luatex` with `shell-escape` enabled (for minted).

I am using a custom document class `PhDthesiscustomCls` for my PhD thesis  (available to download in this [gist here](https://gist.github.com/krishnakumarg1984/d01e67e42ef59efdb23e7738e0b81f1b).)

The class file loads `tikz`, `pgfplots` and a few other tikz/pgf related libraries, and sets up tikz externalisation.

Everything works fine if I exclude the `minted` option from the `tcolorbox` package usage. Things also work if I comment out the `makeglossaries` command. However, when including both of these, the code runs without error **only** if tikzexternalisation is disabled locally, i.e

- Works without the `minted` option when loading `tcolorbox`
- Works without `makeglossaries`
- But when we desire to have both the above features, the code compiles only when `tikz` externalization is disabled locally.

**Why is this happening and how do I fix it?**

Here is minimum example to replicate the problem.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,online,a4paper,pdfa1,biblatex,fontC]{PhDthesiscustomCls}
%\tikzset{external/force remake}

\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox} % problematic with the "minted" option

\usepackage{graphics} % for improved inclusion of graphics
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\loadglsentries{glossary}
\makeglossaries{}

%%%%%%%%%%% Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

% \printglossaries{}

\tikzexternaldisable % force disable externalisation to compile without errors
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example1.tikz}
    \caption{\LaTeX contributions}
\end{figure}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

The `example1.tikz` file here is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = Contributions per category
                          at LaTeX-Community.org,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 1 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {LaTeX, Tools, Distributions, Editors},
    nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates { (57727,LaTeX)         (5672,Tools)
                         (2193,Distributions)  (11106,Editors) };
  \addplot coordinates { (14320,LaTeX)         (1615,Tools)
                         (560,Distributions)   (3075,Editors)  };
  \legend{Topics, Posts}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: can you not replicate with `article.cls` does it depend on that thesis class?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I seriously tried for a couple of hours before giving up.

Comment: `\usepackage{graphics} % for improved inclusion of graphics` seems a strange comment, `graphics` is the basic interface (that you are not using) you want `graphicx` for the `[width=..]` syntax (also it seems odd to use `\includegraphics` to include a tikz file rather than `\input` is that really the syntax defined somewhere?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unless the OP is using `tikzscale`, but I don't think that is compatible with externalisation (if I remember correctly) and I'm not sure that syntax is appropriate for a `pgfplots` figure, also if I remember correctly. (I think both dimensions are needed for plots.)

Comment: You shouldn't use `h` as the sole specifier for a float.

Comment: The glossaries.tex file is missing.  You don't write which error you actually get.  And you don't tell the versions of your tex system and the files -- with lualatex this can matter a lot.

Comment: The glossaries.tex is a single entity. ```\acr{adc}{ADC}{Analog to Digital Converter}```. I am using TL2018 with latest LuaTeX 1.07 I believe. The error is ```something's missing. Perhaps a missing \item``` and in the line where documentclass is defined ```this is only allowed in the preamble```. Everything works fine when disabling externalisation of Tikz.

Comment: @cfr Yes. The class file uses ```\RequirePackage{tikzscale}

``` in line 616. The full class file is downloadable from the gist link.

Comment: I have some concerns with that class file: it loads the deprecated `epsfig` and has a lot of `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` instances (which shouldn't be in a class). It also loads `glossaries` before `hyperref`.

Comment: @Krishna Acronyms are defined using `\newacronym` (or `\newabbreviation`, since `glossaries-extra` has been loaded) not with `\acr`.

Comment: What happens if you move `\makeglossaries` before `\usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}`?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot that results in an error. ```./main.toc|5 error|  Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. ...                                               ...entsline {chapter}{Title Page}{i}{section*.1}```. Furthermore the acr file is not created.

Comment: @Krishna Ulrike's answer indicates that the problem is too many write registers, so have a look at [debug No room for a new \write problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154781). You can reduce the number of write registers required by switching from `glossaries.sty`+`\makeglossaries` to `glossaries-extra.sty`+[`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can be pulled down to the following example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newwrite\blubi
\newwrite\blubii
\newwrite\blubiii
\newwrite\blubiv
\newwrite\blubv
\newwrite\blubvi
\newwrite\blubvii
\newwrite\blubviii
\newwrite\blubix
\newwrite\blubx
\newwrite\blubxi
\newwrite\blubxii


\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex
\tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode
                              -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % \tf@toc=\write16

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw(0,0)--++(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

This example opens a lot of write streams (as does your own example: the `minted` option of `tcolorbox` and `\makeglossaries` both open streams).

With `pdflatex`  you would get at `\tableofcontents` which tries to open stream 16 the well-known error

```
  ! No room for a new \write.
```

lualatex has more write streams and so won't complain. But now you get problems with `pgf`: the package uses in various places `\immediate\write16` for its log messages.

And this means that you get in the toc suddenly lines like

```
  ===== Image 'test-utf8-figure0' is up-to-date. ======
```

which can lead to various errors. Imho this is a bug in pgf and should be reported there.

As a work-around you can try `\newwrite\blub` before `\tableofcontents`. Then the log-messages will no longer end in the toc. Be aware that every change in your document which changes the number of write stream can again led to errors.

I added a bug report for pgf: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/488/

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately, I did not understand enough since this is a bit too technical for my level of TeX knowledge. What is a ```blub```? I don't use it? In practise, does it mean I will face more problems with Tikz externalisation? Would you recommend moving to standard classes such as ```book``` to avoid these issues? I am not sure if I can afford to debug future problems like these.

Comment: `blub` is an arbitrary name. You can also use `\newwrite\someothername`. The problem is not related to your class. You can get it also with book if you load a number of packages. And it is imho not only related to externalisation, also a command from the math parser uses write16. This needs a proper solution. I will ask the latex team about it.

Comment: thank you. Just one more question (I am feeling rather stupid here). I don't explicitly use ```newwrite``` in my document. What is the source of this error in my doc?

Comment: You also said that this is a bug in ```pgf```. I am confused if I should report it in ```pgfplots``` sourceforge page by Dr Christian Feuersanger, or somewhere else. (I thought ```pgf``` was developed originally by Till Tantau but don't see a development page/repo).

Comment: As I wrote: Your packages open them, e.g. every glossary has to open a write stream for the output files for makeindex, minted, has an output stream, tcolorbox, biblatex etc. I will make a bug report at the correct place.

Comment: Thank you again. In the meantime, is there a workaround? I mean, it should be a very common use case to have glossaries, code listings, bibliography  and externalised Tikz in a thesis document ? How does it work for all other people? Are they using some recommended workaround?

Comment: Did you actually read my answer?

Comment: Yes.,..".As a work-around you can try \newwrite\blub before \tableofcontents"... But I am not sure how using more ```newwrites``` can help an already overloaded stream.

Comment: luatex has enough streams. But you need to avoid that stream16 used by pgf is also used by something else. So you should move the toc to 17.

Comment: this workaround did not succeed for me. I now get the error ```no file main.acr```, i.e. ```makeglossaries``` is not producing the ```acr``` file.

Comment: @cfr i doubt it. Luatex has enough streams.

Comment: @cfr There a perhaps other reasons for luatex. Also morewrites can slow down the compilation a lot.

Comment: Just realised the OP is already using LuaTeX. Sorry.