# tcolorbox with minted option + glossaries + biblatex: limitation, incompatibility or bug?

Tags: biblatex, glossaries, tcolorbox, minted, glossaries-extra

An issue occurs when one wants, on one hand, to have more than five "local" glossaries and a main glossary (`glossaries` packages) and, on the other hand, to use also `biblatex` and `tcolorbox` with its `minted` option (LuaLaTeX with --shell-escape option for `minted` and the remainder contents of a class).

The error appears in the sixth "glo file" (here .local06-glo), stipulating in its fist line:

`[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]`

The following test have been done (for up to five local glossaries, all works fine) and give:

1. `minted` + `glossaries` + `biblatex` --> works (6 local glossaries + main)
2. `tcolorbox` (without `minted` option but solely or with all the other options) + `glossaries` + `biblatex` -->  works (6 local glossaries + main)
3. `tcolorbox` with only the minted option + `glossaries` -->  works (6 local glossaries + main)
4. `tcolorbox` with only the minted option + `glossaries` + `biblatex` -->  *fails* (5 local glossaries + main works)

Obviously, if the error line is deleted, the `xindy` application or `makeglossaries` script are running fine.

Thus, is the insolent package is `tcolorbox` with its `minted` option or the responsibility belongs to a linear combination of these three packages which leads to an inconsistency?

A bit tricky for me, firstly because it's the first time I encounter such an error but, mostly because I don't know where to search a solution: these three, or four packages with `minted`, are essential.

*MWE*

```
\begin{filecontents*}{glossary-main.def}
\newglossaryentry{one-main}{
  name={main first},
  description={main first explanation},
}
\newglossaryentry{two-main}{
  name={main second},
  description={main second explanation},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glossary-local01.def}
\newglossaryentry{one-local01}{
  type=local01,
  name={local01 first},
  description={local01 first explanation},
}
\newglossaryentry{two-local01}{
  type=local01,
  name={local01 second},
  description={local01 second explanation},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glossary-local02.def}
\newglossaryentry{one-local02}{
  type=local02,
  name={local02 first},
  description={local02 first explanation},
}
\newglossaryentry{two-local02}{
  type=local02,
  name={local02 second},
  description={local02 second explanation},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glossary-local03.def}
\newglossaryentry{one-local03}{
  type=local03,
  name={local03 first},
  description={local03 first explanation},
}
\newglossaryentry{two-local03}{
  type=local03,
  name={local03 second},
  description={local03 second explanation},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glossary-local04.def}
\newglossaryentry{one-local04}{
  type=local04,
  name={local04 first},
  description={local04 first explanation},
}
\newglossaryentry{two-local04}{
  type=local04,
  name={local04 second},
  description={local04 second explanation},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glossary-local05.def}
\newglossaryentry{one-local05}{
  type=local05,
  name={local05 first},
  description={local05 first explanation},
}
\newglossaryentry{two-local05}{
  type=local05,
  name={local05 second},
  description={local05 second explanation},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{glossary-local06.def}
\newglossaryentry{one-local06}{
  type=local06,
  name={local06 first},
  description={local01 first explanation},
}
\newglossaryentry{two-local06}{
  type=local06,
  name={local06 second},
  description={local06 second explanation},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{book}

% OK with biblatex + glossaries (6 local + main)
%\usepackage{minted}

% OK with biblatex + glossaries (6 local + main)
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% OK with biblatex + glossaries (5 local + main)
% FAILED with biblatex + glossaries (6 local + main)
\tcbuselibrary{minted}% loads also the `minted' package

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}% Before `glossaries`

\usepackage[xindy,section=subsection]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newcommand{\glsmain}[1]{\gls{#1-main}}% For main glossary references

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newglossary*{local01}{Contextual glossary}
\newglossary*{local02}{Contextual glossary}
\newglossary*{local03}{Contextual glossary}
\newglossary*{local04}{Contextual glossary}
\newglossary*{local05}{Contextual glossary}
\newglossary*{local06}{Contextual glossary}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{glossary-main.def}%
\loadglsentries{glossary-local01.def}%
\loadglsentries{glossary-local02.def}%
\loadglsentries{glossary-local03.def}%
\loadglsentries{glossary-local04.def}%
\loadglsentries{glossary-local05.def}%
\loadglsentries{glossary-local06.def}%

\parindent=0pt


\begin{document}


\chapter{First chapter}

\section{Test glossaries}

\lipsum[2]

Main glossary: \glsmain{one}, \glsmain{two}

First local glossary: \gls{one-local01}, \gls{two-local01}.

Second local glossary: \gls{one-local01}, \gls{two-local01}.

Third local glossary: \gls{one-local01}, \gls{two-local01}.

Fourth local glossary: \gls{one-local01}, \gls{two-local01}.

Fifth local glossary: \gls{one-local01}, \gls{two-local01}.

Sixth local glossary: \gls{one-local01}, \gls{two-local01}.


\section{Display local glossaries}

\glsaddallunused[local01]
\printunsrtglossary[type=local01]

\glsaddallunused[local02]
\printunsrtglossary[type=local02]

\glsaddallunused[local03]
\printunsrtglossary[type=local03]

\glsaddallunused[local04]
\printunsrtglossary[type=local04]

\glsaddallunused[local05]
\printunsrtglossary[type=local05]

\glsaddallunused[local06]
\printunsrtglossary[type=local06]


\chapter*{Main glossary}

\glsaddallunused[main]
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

Comment: well it is this problem. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435226/2388. But I don't know yet where the code is that writes to stream 16.

Comment: The culprit is supp-pdf.mkii, it contains a \immediate\write16.

Comment: Try as a workaround `\newcommand\writestatus[2]{}` at the begin of your document (e.g before the \documentclass.)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Many thanks for your prompt replies and efficient workaround. Is this workaround more or less "stable", in the sense that it allows sufficient room for other writes? A couple of days ago, I had a similar issue with many verbatim writes (a bug from my code to store exercises/solutions). If my understanding is correct, by using LuaLaTeX, I thought that there were no limitation (from its documentation, `morewrites` is of no help with LuaTeX).

Comment: The workaround doesn't creates more writes. That is not your problem, luatex has enough writes. The problem is that supp-pdf.mkii writes into your glossary file as it is using a hard coded stream number. We are just discussing how to solve this permantly, but the file is under another copyright so it will need a bit time. The workaround should be unproblematic even if we change something.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks again. I was just trying to see what the `supp-pdf.mkii` file was supposed to do and I noticed that it belongs to the Context environment with another copyright.