# What process can generate a new write sequence

Tags: compiling, glossaries, tex4ht, write

While compiling a very large document recently in `xelatex` and `tex4ht` I have observed that `tex4ht` doesn't handle `write streams` the same as `xelatex`.  I am trying to prepare a MWE to troubleshoot my problem that started when I added another type of glossary to my document.  But I am unable to reproduce the problem in smaller documents.

I don't think it is is specifically a `glossaries` problem because the addition of this sixth glossary doesn't break in a MWE with only 1 example term of each.  My broken project  has nearly 10 thousand entries in a variety of files loaded before the `\begin{document}`.  I am unaware of any entry limit in `glossaries` that would force a cap on the number of entries that can be searched within but I suppose this could be possible and difficult to isolate unless known about in advance.

I make pretty full use of `TeX` automations as a whole:

- cross references to document hierarchy using `\ref{}`
- cross references to figures, tables, and equations using `\cref{}`
- bibliography management for distinct parts, chapters, and sections using `bibunits`
- table of contents and lists for all other types of objects
- Six distinct types of glossaries, and the corresponding `\makeindex`, and `\makeglossaries` and `printglossary[]` calls for appearance customization
- I am sure there are others I use that I am missing.

I have tried to force write calls by including at least one of each in a MWE but I am unable to crash my MWE.

Could anyone provide any advice regarding:

- what other types of package calls create a `new \write`?
- Or what causes distinct `new \write` calls to be made multiple times from the same package.
- Or point me to documentation that describes `tex4ht` limitations regarding `new \write`?
- Maybe all this is unnecessary if `tex4ht` can be forced to permit extra `new \write` streams...

Comment: `tex4ht` surely uses some extra `\writes` for cross referencing

Comment: Why do you think it is a `write` problem?

Comment: @cfr Please excuse the more difficult inline formatting for the sake of presenting my error message from the console in this comment.  The error that I get is `! No room for a new \write . \alloc@ ...else \errmessage {No room for a new #2} fi \fi l.73 \end{document} ?` and according to numerous questions on this site, this  usually is a `write` problem associated with `glossaries`

Comment: Have you tried [morewrites](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/morewrites)?

Comment: @cfr That was easy! Nice answer.  I would be happy to accept this in answer form! I had not tried it, because I remembered reading something that discouraged this.  I instead was trying to use `etex` and `scrwfile`.  If I can find this question again, I will post as a comment for interests sake.

Comment: @EngBIRD I wouldn't recommend loading it as a routine i.e. only load it when you need it. There are some caveats included in the package documentation. For example, spaces in filenames are bad. However, as far as I'm concerned, spaces in filenames are bad news whether I use `morewrites` or not, so I avoid them like the plague. It is using 'Do Not Use' functions i.e. internal stuff which it is better not to use. But, any solution is going to have to interfere with some important, low level stuff. `scrwfile` redirects everything to the `.aux` file. That's messing with stuff, too. If it works...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while ago I ran into this issue in a different context. Searching for answers, [Stephen's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167759/) is the one which I ended up using. [morewrites](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/morewrites) enables more new writes.